# Spring Data: inject 2 repositories with same name but in 2 different packages

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

## Context

I want to use in the same Spring context two different databases that have entities that share the same name, but not the same structure. I rely on Spring Data MongoDB and JPA/JDBC. I have two packages, containing among others the following files:

- com.**bar**.entity

  - Car.class
- com.**bar**.repository

  - CarRepository.class
  - RepoBarMarker.class
- com.**bar**.config

  - MongoConfiguration.class
- com.**foo**.entity

  - Car.class
- com.**foo**.repository

  - CarRepository.class
  - RepoFooMarker.class
- com.**foo**.config

  - JPAConfiguration.class
  - SpecEntityManagerFactory.class

The content of each Car.class is different, I cannot reuse them. **bar** uses Spring-Mongo and **foo** uses Spring-JPA, and repositories are initialised via @EnableMongoRepositories and @EnableJpaRepositories annotations. When in one of my application component I try to access the **foo** version of the repository:

```
@Resource
private com.foo.repository.CarRepository carRepository;
```

I have the following exception when the class containing the @Resource field is created:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'carRepository' must be of type [com.foo.repository.CarRepository], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:446)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    ... 26 more
```

It appears that Spring tries to convert a **bar** repository to a **foo** repository, instead of creating a new bean, as in the same stack I also have the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 implementing com.bar.repository.CarRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.Repository,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.foo.repository.CarRepository]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
        ... 35 more
```

If I try instead to autowire the repository:

```
@Autowire
private com.foo.repository.CarRepository carRepository;
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.foo.CarRepository com.shell.ShellApp.carRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.CarRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 26 more
```

## Spring-data configuration

In **foo** (JPA) package, **JPAConfigration.class**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = RepoFooMarker.class)
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public Session session(final EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {

        final JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

**SpecEntityManagerFactory.class**:

```
@Configuration
public class SpecEntityManagerFactory {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(final DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.entity");
        factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

In **bar** (MongoDB) package, **MongoConfiguration.class**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = RepoBarMarker.class)
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractRepoConfig {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoOperations mongoTemplate() {

        final MongoClient mongo = this.getMongoClient();
        final MongoClientURI mongoUri = this.getMongoClientUri();

        final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, mongoUri.getDatabase());
        mongoTemplate.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);

        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

## Question

If I change in **foo** repository the entity name to CarFoo.class and the repository to CarFooRepository.class, then everything works. But is there away to avoid renaming them and still have a real wiring per type, instead of name (as it is what seems to be done here), for Spring Data repositories?

Comment: Can you please show your Spring Data configuration?

Comment: @geoand Updated with Spring Data configurations. My setup is more complex, I simplified it while keeping the essential Spring Data config part.

Comment: I doubt it will work, but do you mind trying to add `@Repository("fooCarRepository")` on `com.foo.repository.CarRepository`?

Comment: Also you can try adding `@Qualifier("fooCarRepository")` on `com.foo.repository.CarRepository`. Let me know if either works

Comment: @geoand Adding `@Repository("fooCarRepository")` in com.foo.repository.CarRepository works! I tried only the `@Qualifier` option that does not work (unless you also specify that `@Qualifier` when you inject the bean). But `@Repository("fooCarRepository")` is a nice and simple workaround, thanks! It reveals however that wiring is not made simply by type in this case: names also impact.

Comment: I will add the `@Repository` solution as an answer in order for future readers to be able to see it without having to read the comments. If it's not too much trouble, it would be in their best interest to accept it in order for them to be able to immediately know it's correct.

Comment: I would have to check the sources of Spring Data to see how it registers the Spring Bean, but I bet it just used the name of the interface by default

Comment: Done. According to what I have seen, it seems that the name it uses is just the name of the interface, yes, thus causing the "problem". Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you can use

`@Repository("fooCarRepository")`

on the interface declaration of

`com.foo.repository.CarRepository`

Although when using Spring Data `@Repository` is **not** generally needed on the interface, however in your case you need to supply it. That's because you need to make Spring register the implementation of the bean with a custom name (in this case `fooCarRepository`) in order to avoid the name collision.

Comment: So in effect Spring is ignoring the package??

Comment: @KeesdeKooter I am not sure I understand :(

Comment: @geond `com.foo.repository.CarRepository` is a different class than `com.bar.repository.CarRepository` but apparently spring only uses the classname and not the package name as the default bean name. And it does not warn you of duplicates.